# Is there any inbuilt Function for string contains a Currency Symbol or not?

Tags: c#, wpf, string

Hi I am new and learning WPF .I have a TextBox and user inputs in it and I want to know is there any Currency symbol in that user input or not.Is there any inbuilt function to check this ? if not then how I can do that.Thanks

Comment: I dont get what you mean.

Comment: @Prisoner He means he wants to check if a string i.e. contains any of the follow "£/$/€/etc."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 bool hasCurrencySymbol = textBox.Text.Any(s=>char.GetUnicodeCategory(s)==System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.CurrencySymbol);
```

Not sure about any such method . but you can create your own extension method using [UnicodeCategory enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static bool HasCurrencySymbol(this string input)
    {
        return input.Any(s => char.GetUnicodeCategory(s) == System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.CurrencySymbol);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.